# setting form to look like this image?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

is it advisable to play with the controls to make my form look like this or should i just use this graphic and place it in the background. if the former, then please suggest which controls on the form i can tweak to make the form look like this?

[alt text http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2351/huesaturation.jpg](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2351/huesaturation.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create something like this, I would suggest moving from winforms to Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) if you have the option. There is much better support for creating these type of rich interfaces in WPF, although it does mean introducing a .NET 3.0+ requirement to your application.

To get you started, here are some tutorials:

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/WPFTutorial.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299.aspx

Comment: how come i cant do this in winforms? what is WPF?

Comment: You probably could do it in Winforms, but you would be going to a lot of effort to get it to look just right. WPF stands for Windows Presentation Foundation. It was introduced in .NET 3.0, and is capable of creating just this type of interface.